# awk -F is not searching for full string in solaris

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am using `awk -F` command in `echo` output as below. it prints based on the First Character match instead of Full string match.

**Note:** This is working in Linux box but not working for solaris.

**sample.txt**

```
-bash-3.00$ cat sample.txt

Hello
How are
You
Hello
How are you
Hello how
-bash-3.00$
```

**Commands:**

```
-bash-3.00$ b=`cat sample.txt `
-bash-3.00$ echo $b
Hello How are You Hello How are you Hello how
-bash-3.00$ echo $b | awk -F"Hello" '{print $2}'
ello
```

**Expected is :**

> How are you ... (Text after "Hello" String)

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're seeing. It works as expected for me. The output is ` How are You`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : I am using solaris

Comment: @logan use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` if you're on solaris.

Comment: @jaypal : ya, its working :) why is it ?

Comment: `awk` on solaris is broken. So users should refrain that from using.

Comment: @jaypal : Thanks. Please add it as answer so that i can accept

Comment: @logan Done, I added a link for reference. It should prevent you from several hours of useless debugging. `:)`

Comment: Also use double quotes in `echo "$b"` unless you specifically want to lose whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular `awk` on solaris is old and broken. Here is a [good write up](http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk) on the cons of it. Users are highly recommended to use `nawk`, `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or install a copy of `gnu awk`.

Comment: So instead of awk , what is the command can be used to achieve the same result both in solaris and linux for all kind of awk operations

Comment: If you build something that works with `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk` then it should work on linux. Building something on `linux` using features of `gnu awk` only might cause portability issues.